# Multicast echo server

Tags: c, sockets, unix, udp, multicast

This is more of a conceptual confusion. I am making a multicast server which just echoes back the datagram received.Here's the code

```
    while (1) {
         cnt = recvfrom(sock, message, sizeof(message), 0, 
                (struct sockaddr *) &addr, &addrlen);
         //printf("%d \n",cnt);
         if (cnt < 0) {
            perror("recvfrom");
            exit(1);
         } else if (cnt == 0) {
            break;
         }
         printf("%s: message = \"%s\"\n", inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr), message);
         addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(EXAMPLE_GROUP);
         cnt = sendto(sock, message, sizeof(message), 0,
          (struct sockaddr *) &addr, addrlen);
         if (cnt < 0) {
            perror("sendto");
            exit(1);
         }

    }
```

The problem with this is as a multicast server will also receive the datagram. So, after it recieves a datagram, it sends, it again recieves the same datagram, and so on entering an infinite loop. Any pointers on how to implement such type of server?

Comment: The server doesn't need to join the multicast group. Only the clients do.

Comment: if you want to use multicast to send to the server and also to the clients, use different groups for each direction.

Comment: @Barmar I need to implement the client and server in a single file. Can you please elaborate. Specification goes like this- Server sends a datagram every 15 seconds, it counts the number of hosts on multicast(running the same program) on receiving their replies till 5 seconds as each process echoes the datagram received.

Comment: @Barmar That is not correct. It has nothing to do with clients and servers. The *receiver* needs to join the multicast group: the *sender* does not. In this case the receiver is a server.

Comment: @EJP IIUC, the purpose of this is that clients send a message to the server, and it echoes it back out so all the clients receive it. So client->server should be unicast, server->clients should be multicast. The server doesn't need to listen on the multicast socket.

Comment: @Barmar  You're making assumptions. It isn't clear from the OP's description whether it is the server or the clients who are doing the multicasting here, or both. His comment above only confuses the issue even further.

Comment: either way, there's no reason to be using the same multicast group for the client and server.

Comment: There is no client, just a same program which can join as a client or a server once executed. Below answer answers my query anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is what EJP said, to disable multicast loopback so that the sending machine doesn't receive a copy of its own multicast packet back.  However, be aware that if you do that, you won't be able to test with clients and server all running on the same machine anymore, since [IP_MULTICAST_LOOP is implemented at the IP routing level](http://developerweb.net/viewtopic.php?id=5387).

A second possible option to avoid infinite packet loops would be to have the echo-server send its response packets to a different multicast group than the one it listens on (or even have it send its responses via unicast rather than multicast; the server could call recvfrom() to find out the unicast source address of any packet it receives, so it's easy for it to know where to send the reply packet back to)

A third option would be to modify the contents of the packet somehow to mark it as already-seen, so that your server knows not to echo it a second time.  For example, you could specify that your server will only echo packets whose first byte is set to zero, and when your server echoes a packet, it makes sure to set the packet's first byte to one before send()-ing it out.  (Your clients would need to be aware of this convention, of course)

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable multicast loopback via `setsockopt().`